# Y-ticks not appearing in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,4))
plt.autoscale(False)

xtickmin = np.arange(0,490001,2500)
xtickmaj = np.arange(0,490001,100000)
ytickmaj = np.arange(560,200,50)

ytickmin = np.arange(560,200,10)

ax.set_xlim(0,495000)
ax.set_ylim(200,560)

ax.set_xticks(xtickmaj)
ax.set_xticks(xtickmin, minor=True)

ax.set_yticks(ytickmaj)
ax.set_yticks(ytickmin, minor=True)

print(ax.get_xticks())

plt.grid(which="major", alpha=1)
plt.grid(which="minor", alpha=0.33)

#plt.minorticks_on()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.plot(plotresult)

plt.savefig("graph.png", dpi=600)
```

`plt` is `matplotlib.pyplot` and `plotresult` is a list with the values I want to graph.

Even though I set the y ticks with `ax.set_yticks()` it does not appear.

Doing the same with x-ticks works fine. Another evidence for this is that `ax.get_yticks()` returns an empty list whereas `ax.get_xticks()` returns the ticks as expected.

Also, `plt.minorticks_on()` actually turns off the minor ticks for some bizarre reason, so it's commented out.

Comment: Well `np.arange(560,200,50)` is empty. You'd need `np.arange(200,560,50)` or maybe `np.arange(550,199,-50)`.

Comment: @JohanC  That was indeed the problem, thanks!